# You might not find me adorable, but I sound like I could be

Tags: riddle

What am I?

> I can be found in many places and in many different forms.
>
> You might not find me adorable, but I sound like I could be.
>
> People usually try and get rid one form of me, even though I cause no harm.
>
> My other name sounds like I could be equestrian.
>
> My friends think I am superficial, but I’d like to think I am a protector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you...

> a [cuticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuticle)?

I can be found in many places and in many different forms.

> In humans: the base of a fingernail, the outer cellular layer of a hair. In arthropods, the exoskeleton. In plants, a waxy hydrophobic covering.

You might not find me adorable, but I sound like I could be.

> "Cuticle" sounds like "cute" (note: this clue specifically was what led me to the answer)

People usually try and get rid one form of me, even though I cause no harm.

> Apparently people try to get rid of the eponychium, the thin skin at the base of their nail, for cosmetic reasons. People are strange...

My other name sounds like I could be equestrian.

> [Eponychium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponychium) sounds like "pony"

My friends think I am superficial, but I’d like to think I am a protector.

> The eponychium is actually very important for preventing bacterial infection

Comment: You are very close, you even mention the answer in your response! @ferret

Comment: @MicCrozier updated... hopefully I am warmer and not colder!

Comment: You are correct!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> A cacoon

I can be found in many places and in many different forms.

> This may be referring to the different forms of a caterpillar, but cacoons are found in different places and they also can look different based on the species.

You might not find me adorable, but I sound like I could be.

> Some pepole don't like the white looking ones and find them creepy. Cacoon sounds like a cute word I guess?

People usually try and get rid one form of me, even though I cause no harm.

> When the season is right, caterpillars come crawling out EVERYWHERE and some people find them a nuisance or are scared of them.

My other name sounds like I could be equestrian

> Castillonais is a type of horse and it kinda sounds like chrysalis , the other name for a cacoon

My friends think I am superficial, but I’d like to think I am a protector.

> While in the pupa (cacoon) stage, the caterpillar turns into a butterfly which is pretty. (Or it could turn into a scary moth) The cacoon protects the caterpillar.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect! :) @PaigeMeinke

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Sweat

I can be found in many places and in many different forms.

> There are different types of sweating in different parts of our body.

You might not find me adorable, but I sound like I could be.

> The word sweat isn't adorable but the word sweet which does sound like sweat, is adorable.

People usually try and get rid one form of me, even though I cause no harm.

> People use napkins or towels to get rid of sweating even though it causes no harm.

My other name sounds like I could be equestrian.

> I didn't get this part.

My friends think I am superficial, but I’d like to think I am a protector.

> Sweating is on the surface of the body parts. And it actually protects our health.

Comment: Sorry, incorrect! :) @ran